# Prevent TreeFile click on Qooxdoo?

Tags: qooxdoo

Recently I develop an qooxdoo application which have several forms. I manage the form in a Tree, so user can easily navigate to every form by clicking an item in the tree then the corresponding form will be shown in the main Container. My question is, if user make any changes in one form and haven't save it yet then they try to navigate to another form by clicking the tree item, the application should show an alert. So I must able to prevent the form being shown up. If this possible in qooxdoo? And how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You could set the tree container to disabled as soon as any change in the form ocures and enable it again whenever the form is saved ... additionally you might display a note on the tree: "Save form to reenable tree navigation" whenever the tree gets disabled ... why let the user do a useless click on the tree only to popup a note that he can not do it ...